# nullable types to object

Tags: c#

Using dotnet 2.0. Can the following code be improved in style ?

```
    private object GetObj_Version1(int? num)
    {
        return num ?? (object)DBNull.Value;
    }
```

The cast looks a bit messy to me.
Version2 below avoids the cast, but its long winded :

```
    private object GetObj_Version2(int? num)
    {
        object numObj;
        if (num.HasValue)
            numObj = num.Value;
        else
            numObj = DBNull.Value;

        return numObj;
    }
```

Can you think of an alternative which is both short and avoids the cast ? TIA.

Comment: Why do you need to turn a nullable type into an object?

Comment: The returned object would be used to set System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter.Value .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The cast, in this case, does nothing at runtime - it is there purely for the compiler. If you really hate it, perhaps:

```
    static readonly object NullObject = DBNull.Value;
    private object GetObj_Version1(int? num)
    {
        return num ?? NullObject;
    }
```

But I'd leave it myself. As an aside - since you are going to box it anyway, you could dispense with the overload, and just work with `object` - then you don't even need the `static` field:

```
    private object GetObj_Version1(object value)
    {
        return value ?? DBNull.Value;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. Looks like I'll stick with the cast, especially since there's no runtime penalty in this case.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert values to the database, then you can directly pass the nullable type as a procedure's parameter.

```
param.Add("@Param1", nullableParam);
```

Comment: Not quite; if the nullableParam doesn't have a value, then it will be boxed to `null` - and a parameter with a `null` value is not sent. So if there is a non-null default to a SP etc, then this does something different. Of course, you could use this and then "fix up" the parameter values before executing the command.